# How to convert one time zone to another in Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am reading from PostgreSQL into Spark Dataframe and have date column in PostgreSQL like below:

```
last_upd_date
---------------------
"2021-04-21 22:33:06.308639-05"
```

But in spark dataframe it's adding the hour interval.

```
eg: 2020-04-22 03:33:06.308639
```

Here it is adding 5 hours to the last_upd_date column.

But I want output as 2021-04-21 22:33:06.308639

Can anyone help me how to fix this spark dataframe.

Comment: So you want to store it as timestamp with timezone GMT-5?

Comment: Basically hour interval is depending on day light saving. If the month is Jan, Feb, Dec and Nov then it is -4  otherwise -5.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an [udf](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#udf%5BRT,A1,A2%5D(f:(A1,A2)=%3ERT)(implicitevidence$6:reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag%5BRT%5D,implicitevidence$7:reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag%5BA1%5D,implicitevidence$8:reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag%5BA2%5D):org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction) that formats the timestamp with the required timezone:

```scala
import java.time.{Instant, ZoneId}

val formatTimestampWithTz = udf((i: Instant, zone: String)
    => i.atZone(ZoneId.of(zone))
        .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS")))

val df = Seq(("2021-04-21 22:33:06.308639-05")).toDF("dateString")
  .withColumn("date", to_timestamp('dateString, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSx"))
  .withColumn("date in Berlin", formatTimestampWithTz('date, lit("Europe/Berlin")))
  .withColumn("date in Anchorage", formatTimestampWithTz('date, lit("America/Anchorage")))
  .withColumn("date in GMT-5", formatTimestampWithTz('date, lit("-5")))

df.show(numRows = 10, truncate = 50, vertical = true)
```

Result:

```
-RECORD 0------------------------------------------
 dateString        | 2021-04-21 22:33:06.308639-05 
 date              | 2021-04-22 05:33:06.308639    
 date in Berlin    | 2021-04-22 05:33:06.308639    
 date in Anchorage | 2021-04-21 19:33:06.308639    
 date in GMT-5     | 2021-04-21 22:33:06.308639
```